# How to use ipmitool bridging

Tags: ipmi

I read the bridging section in 'man' several times but it might as well be written in Greek (or perhaps I fundamentally misunderstand what it is).

Suppose that I have two server nodes (A and B), each one has an IPMI controller.

Nodes are connected to the network and I can access them remotely.

Their IPMI controllers are also connected to the network, but they sit on a different switch, and, for some reason (probably because network admins screwed up), I can't reach them. (I can do 'sudo ipmitool lan print' on A, and it tells me the IP address of the corresponding controller, but I can't communicate with that IP.)

Node B suffers a failure and I need to reboot it. I know the IP of its IPMI controller.

How do I tell the controller of A to communicate a reboot command to the controller of B?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the "bridging" feature in ipmitool has nothing to do with accessing other controllers over the network – its purpose is to access controllers available on the I2C bus through an [ICMB bridge](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/icmb-spec-v1-rev1.3.pdf) (e.g. if you have a "chassis" IPMI controller which directly connects to "blade server" IPMI controllers via I2C).

To reach another IPMI controller over LAN, you will actually need to reach that LAN from the host.

Comment: That would make sense. How can I determine if the controller of A is connected to any others via that bridge?